# Can auto placeholder be used to deduce function result in non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider simple example:

```
template <auto(*X)()>
struct Foo {
    decltype(X()) x;
};

int bar();

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(Foo<bar>{});
}
```

Both [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r8gYDmpoLfzL2k9x) and [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OjN9wrgroFq5Bk0M) seem to accept the code. Is the code really c++17 compliant? If so is there some other rule that makes the following code ill formed?

```
template <class T, auto(*X)(T)>
struct Foo {
    decltype(X(0)) x;
};

int bar(int);

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(Foo<int, bar>{});
}
```

This one makes only [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xu6b8Tt0NgG0gZTE) unhappy.

Error message:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:9:35: error: unable to deduce 'auto (*)(T)' from 'bar'
     static_cast<void>(Foo<int, bar>{});
                                   ^
prog.cc:9:35: note:   mismatched types 'T' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `auto` may be used [inside a compound type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) ([[temp.param]/4.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4.6), [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct)).  I believe that gcc is in error in your second example: your explicitly specified `T` of `int` is substituted before performing deduction ([temp.deduct]/2.3, /5, and /6, referenced by [dcl.type.auto.deduct]/2.3 and /4).

Comment: Where does the standard guarantee that the substituting is performed before the deducing?

Comment: @xskxzr: Added.  gcc/clang even support `template<auto N,class T> void f(T(&)[N]);` although they disagree about the resulting type of `N`.  I have a harder time seeing that in the wording, since it requires deducing `N` and _then_ its type.