# Can placeholder type in non-type template parameter involve overload resolution of the function passed as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

A follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481057/can-auto-placeholder-be-used-to-deduce-function-result-in-non-type-template-para). Assuming placeholder can be used to deduce result type of the function pointer constituting non-type template parameter. Does c++17 allows to perform overload resolution on passed to the template function name - without the knowledge of the result type, that would be needed to perform implicit casting?

```
template <auto(*)(int)>
struct Foo { };

int bar(int);
float bar(float);

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(Foo<bar>{});
}
```

[[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QPEF9ek3LxAtQvq2) as well as [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qlvAYthDOcqB1Sr8) seem to accept the code.

Comment: [Probably](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#1.7).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Nice!! I think it covers the question, thanks!

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think the bullet was already there in c++14... :o What was the usage of this bullet back then?

Comment: Same as the usage is now. Except you'd pick a specific function from an overload set, where you specify the return type yourself for the template parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed according to the [very bullet **Rakete1111** pointed out](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.over#1.7). And there's no need to just assume it can be done, it's done according to the rules of placeholder type deduction at [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4), emphasis mine:

> If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type T'
>   replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument
>   deduction. Obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with
>   either a new invented type template parameter U or, if the
>   initialization is copy-list-initialization, with
>   std​::​initializer_­list. **Deduce a value for U using the rules of
>   template argument deduction from a function call, where P is a
>   function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is e.**
>   If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, T'
>   is obtained by substituting the deduced U into P.

Where [[temp.deduct.call]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#6) has this paragraph, pertaining to your use case:

> When P is a function type, function pointer type, or pointer to member
>   function type:
>
> - If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function templates, the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.
> - If the argument is an overload set (not containing function templates), trial argument deduction is attempted using each of the
>     members of the set. **If deduction succeeds for only one of the
>     overload set members, that member is used as the argument value for
>     the deduction.** If deduction succeeds for more than one member of the
>     overload set the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.

So there you have it in all its glory.

Comment: What I was missing was your last quoted paragraph :)

Comment: Superb! Pity gcc has a nasty bug in its implementation of auto template parameters as it would make a very powerful mechanism... Thanks!!!